# How to manage USB devices between host and guest with VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox, webcam

I would like to make my host computer’s webcam available to my guest OS under VirtualBox. Having never shared USB devices between the two before, though, I am a bit skittish about the language in the VirtualBox user guide on [USB settings](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-usb):

> As soon as the guest system starts using a USB device, it will appear
>   as unavailable on the host... On a Windows host, you will need to
>   unplug and reconnect a USB device to use it after creating a filter
>   for it

If I were to share my host’s integrated webcam, relinquishing control to the guest OS, how would I restore control to the host since I cannot unplug the webcam?

(My host is Windows 8 and my guest is Windows 7.)

Comment: I do not know what is possible with VirtualBox but on VMware Workstation in the context menu of the icon of a connected USB device there is `Disconnect (Connect to host)` which really reconnects the device back to the host.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should create usb filter, follow this:

1. Open the VM setting (this is your Windows 7).
2. Go to the USB tab and make sure Enable USB Controller has checked. You can check the USB 2.0 but you have to install vmbox extensions.
3. Click the add button and select the webcam, done.
4. Now you can replug your USB device and start the Windows 7 to see whether is succeed